# Can't delete SQLite Database entry with EditText and Button

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to implement a method, so I can enter a value (integer) into an edittext field and click a button to delete an SQLite Database entry. I can't seem to get it to work though.

Here is the method in the DatabaseManager class:

```
public void deleteEntry(Integer entryid){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete("data", "entryid" + "=\"" + entryid + "\"", null);
}
```

Here is the declaration in the activity class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    _btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    _etDelete = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDelete);
    db = new DatabaseManager(this);

    _btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    
    }
```

And here is the method I'm calling in the Activity, when the delete button is clicked:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
[...]
else if (v.equals(_btnDelete)){
            Integer val = Integer.parseInt(_etDelete.getText().toString());
            db.deleteEntry(val);
        }
```

And here is the layout for the EditText and Button:

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etDelete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="Enter ID to delete"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Delete"/>
```

And lastly, the Database scheme:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

    try{
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE data (" +
                "entryid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "name TEXT," +
                "weight INTEGER," +
                "reps INTEGER," +
                "entrytime TEXT)"
        );
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance :))

Answer (score 0):

Try using :-

```
db.delete("data", "entryid=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(entryid)});
```

Re comment:-

> Unfortunately that didn't change anything, ....

I believe that you also need to change :-

```
else if (v.equals(_btnDelete)){
            Integer val = Integer.parseInt(_etDelete.getText().toString());
            db.deleteEntry(val);
        }
```

to

```
else if (view.getId() == R.id.btnDelete){
            Integer val = Integer.parseInt(_etDelete.getText().toString());
            db.deleteEntry(val);
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything, I now changed the method in the DatabaseManager to:

 `public Integer deleteEntry(String entryid){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("data", "entryid=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(entryid)});
    }`

and called it like this in the activity:

`else if (v.equals(_btnDelete)) {
                Integer deletedRows = db.deleteEntry(_etDelete.getText().toString());
                }`

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @David see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void deleteEntry(Integer entryid){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete("data", "entryid" + "='" + entryid + "'", null);
}
```

Although **"** is more recently supported, it is better for **'** to denote SQL strings.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, the entry still remains after clicking the button. I've now tried to implement it like this:

`public void deleteEntry(Integer entryid){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("data", "entryid" + "='" + entryid + "'", null);
    }`


and

`db.deleteEntry(Integer.valueOf(_etDelete.getText().toString()));`

But that also doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

try  this it may help you

```
public void removeSingleItem(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        long result = database.delete(TableName, "id=?", new String[]{id});
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item Not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).